# Looking for the most elementary proof that $48X^4+12X^2+1=Y^2$ has no non-trivial integer solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

As relayed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670607/is-there-a-general-method-to-determine-the-non-solutions-to-ax4bx2c-y2) of mine (which is more general in scope), I believe I have found a relatively easy, and completely elementary, way to show that the equation
$$48X^4 + 12X^2+1 = Y^2$$
has only the trivial integer solution $(x,y) = (0, \pm 1)$. I did it by reducing it, via fairly trivial means, to the equation $$w(w+1)=12z^2(16z^2+1),$$ setting
\begin{align}
w &= ab,  & 12z^2 &= ac, \\
w+1 &= cd, & 16z^2+1 &= bd,
\end{align}
and then manipulating those until I could show that $a=0$ (implying $w=z=0$, leading back to $x=0$, as claimed).

Now I'm wondering if anyone else has a better elementary solution.

Comment: Why can't $12$ be split over $w$ and $w+1$?

Comment: @martycohen: It can. That simply means that (e.g.) $3 \mid a$ and $4 \mid c$.

Comment: Do you handle those cases?

Comment: @martycohen: It's handled automatically (implicitly) by the construction: one side of the equation is factored as $ab \cdot cd$, and the other as $ac \cdot bd$. This covers every possible integer factorization.