# Solving a Diophantine equation involving fourth powers and squares

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to show that $x^4 - 3y^4=z^2$ has no solutions over the positive integers. I tried working on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but couldn't go far. Factorizing didn't do much either.

Comment: Mordell's book does several similar results; I'll check.

Comment: yes. page 23. $x^4 - p y^4 = z^2$  has only trivial solutions when  $ p \equiv 3,-3,-5 \pmod {16}  $   which includes your example.

Comment: proof is on page 24

Comment: I don't have the book available, and I couldn't find it online. Would you mind sharing the proof?

Comment: The only non-negative solutions are when $y=0$ where $z=x^2$ or when $x=y=z=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a positive integer solution, with $y$ minimal, of

$$ x^4-3y^4=z^2\tag{1}$$

We can suppose that $x,y,z$ are pairwise coprime  since a common factor of any pair of $x,y,z$ would be a factor of all and cancellation could occur. Then, considered modulo $8$ we see that $y$ is even. We rewrite the equation as

$$\left (\frac{x^2-z}{2}\right )\left (\frac{x^2+z}{2}\right)=12t^4.$$
Since the two bracketed factors, $L$ and $M$ say, differ by the odd integer $z$ and have integer product, they are both integers. Furthermore, if $q$ is a prime common factor of $L$ and $M$, then $q$ would be a factor of both $x$ and $z$, a contradiction.

Therefore $\{L,M\}=\{au^4,cv^4\}$, where $ac=12$ and $t=uv$, with $u$ and $v$ coprime, and $$au^4+cv^4=x^2.$$ Since $x$ is odd the only possibility is
$u^4+12v^4=x^2.$ (Note that $4u^4+3v^4=x^2$ is not possible modulo $4$). Then
$$\left (\frac{u^2-x}{2}\right )\left (\frac{u^2+x}{2}\right)=-3v^4.$$
Since the two bracketed factors, $L$ and $M$ say, differ by the  integer $x$ and have integer product, they are both integers. Furthermore, if $q$ is a prime common factor of $L$ and $M$, then $q$ would be a factor of both $x$ and $u$, a contradiction.
Therefore $\{L,M\}=\{aU^4,cV^4\}$, where $ac=-3$ and $v=UV$, with $U$ and $V$ coprime, and $$aU^4+cV^4=u^2.$$ Modulo $3$ the only possibility is $\{a,c\}=\{1,-3\}.$ From a solution $(x,y,z)$ of  equation (1) we have therefore deduced a second solution $(X,Y,Z)$, where $$Y=\frac{y}{2UX}<y,$$ a contradiction.

**NOTE**

This is the method used on

[Does the equation $y^2=3x^4-3x^2+1$ have an elementary solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003984/does-the-equation-y2-3x4-3x21-have-an-elementary-solution/4004298#4004298)